# Как скомпилировать программу программу на c# 6 под .net 4.5

Tags: c#, winforms, компиляция

В интернете, насколько я понял, говорится, что на c# 6 нельзя компилировать программы (CSharpCodeProvider) под .net 4.5, только под 4.6. Однако в VisualStudio проект 4.5 поддерживал все его языковые возможности. Как они это сделали? Можно это повторить в моем проекте?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921749/6808809

Comment: То есть мне нужно установить Rolsyn?

Comment: @Antinet Нет. В Project->Properties ставите Build->Advanced->Language version нужную версию языка, а в Application->Target framework нужный фреймворк. Так можно хоть на C# 7.3 писать под .Net 2.0.

Comment: А как это сделать, когда нужно собрать программу из программы?

Comment: "*То есть мне нужно установить Rolsyn?*" - установить Rolsyn нужно для того, чтобы вообще собирать c# 6.0, под любую .NET. Собственно, с Visual Studio 2015+ он уже идет в комплекте. Ответ по ссылке говорит, что в принципе можно, это зависит от того, что именно из C# 6 вы используете.

Comment: Я собираю программу из другой программы, и некоторые части кода крайне желательно должны использовать c# 6 (а лучше - 7).